# Precious Metals API/Webservice wanted

Tags: xml, api, webservice-client

Is there a free webservice/api (on Yahoo or other platforms) that can return live stock prices for precious metals rates (Gold, Silver, Platinium, Palladium)?

Here is a paid service : http://www.kitco.com/market/

(It would be great if it comes from Yahoo Query Language)

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same thing, and so far have only been able to find [this xml webservice](http://services.packetizer.com/spotprices/). Unfortunately it's only updated at the end of the day, so it's not really live.

Answer (score 3):

if you need a free and hourly updated one - this [Precious Metals XML Feed](http://www.xmlcharts.com/precious-metals.html) is perfect for you.

Comment: Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.

Comment: it's not more free however

Answer (score 2):

in my point of view, you should use the REST service from goldalert.com. By using firebug you will be able to explore the service through the site's free chart at http://www.goldalert.com/gold-chart/ticker.html.

Comment: This site can’t be reached - www.goldalert.com’s server IP address could not be found.