# Read text in image with PHP

Tags: php, curl, image-processing, ocr, gd

I'm trying to read the text from this image:

[image]

I want to read the price, e.g. **"`EUR42721.92`"**

I tried these libraries:

1. [How to Create a PHP Captcha Decoder with PHP OCR Class: Recognize text & objects in graphical images - PHP Classes](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/2874-PHP-Recognize-text-objects-in-graphical-images.html)
2. [phpOCR: Optical Character Recognizer written in PHP](http://phpocr.sourceforge.net/)

But they don't work. How can I read the text?

Comment: Why it doesn't work? Do you get some error messages?

Comment: Both script didnt read text and numbers.. Example: EUR42450.92 >> output is like: 787988.. I want like this; http://www.free-ocr.com/

Comment: tesseract (http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is en opensource OCR library/program. I had pretty decent results with it.

Comment: tesseract works with php?..

Comment: How about saving yourself some effort? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791189/precious-metals-api-webservice-wanted

Comment: @Bora: through the command line.

Comment: Customer wants from only goldprice.org data

Comment: @Bora  i use tesseract .. the best he can get is `cam EuR42776 a4v27 n2` except with training with that font type

Comment: Is it possible that goldprice.org is providing the prices only as graphic files to prevent screen scraping? They might object to you using their data in this way. Do they have any terms+conditions on the site that you would be breaking by doing this? Do they provide an API you could use instead?

Comment: If the text is gonna be in the same position (x,y to x2,y2) you could cut that area of the image and try OCR on that.

Comment: The first thing to do in this case is isolate the text image, cropping the original image. For that, you need to make some assumptions, for instance: the text is black (#000000) and it's above gray (#C0C0C0) pixels. Enlarge the cropped image to make the OCR process easier. I sent a working example as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (it worked with me):

```
$imagick = new Imagick($filePath);

$size = $imagick->getImageGeometry();
$width     = $size['width'];
$height    = $size['height'];
unset($size);

$textBottomPosition = $height-1;
$textRightPosition = $width;

$black = new ImagickPixel('#000000');
$gray  = new ImagickPixel('#C0C0C0');

$textRight  = 0;
$textLeft   = 0;
$textBottom = 0;
$textTop    = $height;

$foundGray = false;

for($x= 0; $x < $width; ++$x) {
    for($y = 0; $y < $height; ++$y) {
        $pixel = $imagick->getImagePixelColor($x, $y);
        $color = $pixel->getColor();
        // remove alpha component
        $pixel->setColor('rgb(' . $color['r'] . ','
                         . $color['g'] . ','
                         . $color['b'] . ')');

        // find the first gray pixel and ignore pixels below the gray
        if( $pixel->isSimilar($gray, .25) ) {
            $foundGray = true;
            break;
        }

        // find the text boundaries 
        if( $foundGray && $pixel->isSimilar($black, .25) ) {
            if( $textLeft === 0 ) {
                $textLeft = $x;
            } else {
                $textRight = $x;
            }

            if( $y < $textTop ) {
                $textTop = $y;
            }

            if( $y > $textBottom ) {
                $textBottom = $y;
            }
        }
    }
}

$textWidth = $textRight - $textLeft;
$textHeight = $textBottom - $textTop;
$imagick->cropImage($textWidth+10, $textHeight+10, $textLeft-5, $textTop-5);
$imagick->scaleImage($textWidth*10, $textHeight*10, true);

$textFilePath = tempnam('/temp', 'text-ocr-') . '.png';
$imagick->writeImage($textFilePath);

$text = str_replace(' ', '', shell_exec('gocr ' . escapeshellarg($textFilePath)));
unlink($textFilePath);
var_dump($text);
```

You need ImageMagick extension and GOCR installed to run it.
If you can't or don't want to install the ImageMagick extension, I'll send you a GD version with a function to calculate colors distances (it's just an extended Pythagorean Theorem).

Don't forget to set the $filePath value.

[image: image parsing for cropping visualization]

The image shows that it looks for a gray pixel to change the $foundGray flag.
After that, it looks for the first and last pixels from the left and from the top.
It crops the image with some padding, the resulting image is resized and it's saved to a temporary file. After that, it's easy to use gocr (or any other OCR command or library). The temporary file can be removed after that.

Answer (score 0):

Improve the quality of the image of the numbers before you start the OCR. Use a drawing program to improve the quality (bigger size, straight lines).

You can either modify the PHP scripts and adapt the pattern recognition to your needs. 
https://github.com/ogres/PHP-OCR/blob/master/Image2String.php

Or try out other OCR tools:
https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php